# How to make a boolean false inside a while loop using a scanner

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean, java.util.scanner

I'm coding a simple project but i face a very small problem here. To be honest I don't know the right logic for my problem

I have a while condition there so that it will not stop recieveing inputs. I want to stop the input just by typing 'compute' but it gives me errors because I really don't know how to insert that 'compute' thingy after that output of System.out.println(bla bla)

```
    int discreteNum;
    double prob;
    boolean condition = true;
    String forComput;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);

    //These are just outputs, they're harmless
    System.out.println("Mean of Discrete Random Variable \n");
    System.out.print("Instructions:\n");
    System.out.print("Please enter a discrete random variable with its 
    probability\n type 'compute' for the expected value\n");


    while(condition = true ){
    discreteNum = input.nextInt();
    prob = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("( " + discreteNum + "," + prob + " )");


}
        //This code below, I just put it here. 
        //It's just my insight. I tried it but it did not  work. 
        //It's worthy to be deleted here but I just want to show you 

    forComput = str.nextLine();
     if(forComput == "compute"){
      condition = false;
      System.out.println("End!");
}
```

This is how my code works

first input preview: 
[image: first input preview:]

now , my second input:
[image: second input preview]

now, I am attempting to end my input by typing compute , which is i don't know how. pardon
[image: compute error preview 1]

in case you are intereseted with the errors, here they are:
[image]

I really don't know the logic for it. i just tried

Comment: your code is broken at several spots...

Comment: while (condition = true )

Comment: if(forComput == "compute"){

Comment: you have "while(condition=true)"  in first while loop, should be "==" just a heads up

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It's over... the question is dead.... the fight is lost... don't descent further into madness...

Comment: the code that you think you are having a problem with is never being run. You are stuck in the first while loop, when you type "compute" the scanner is expecting an int (since you call scanner.nextInt())...

Comment: So is it possible to execute that "compute" thingy code in the while loop? Any remedy?

Comment: "So is it possible to execute that 'compute' thingy code in the while loop? Any remedy?" – jerome_mjt **->**
"I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."  – Charles Babbage